# How To Load View In Codeigniter Not In The Views Folder

Tags: codeigniter

i want to make the different themes for my application . i kept all the theme folders in the http:://example.com/thems/,.. i want to load the views form these themes folder to make the custom template .

Answer (score 2):

Just extend the CI_Loader core class.
Create new file at application/core/MY_Loader.php and extend the __construct method

```
class My_Loader extends CI_Loader
{
   function __construct()
   {
      //Change this property to match your new path
      $this->_ci_view_path = APPPATH.'views/';
      $this->_ci_ob_level  = ob_get_level();
      $this->_ci_library_paths = array(APPPATH, BASEPATH);
      $this->_ci_helper_paths = array(APPPATH, BASEPATH);
      $this->_ci_model_paths = array(APPPATH);
      log_message('debug', "Loader Class Initialized");
   }
}
```

I am quite interested if this little hack will work :)

Answer (score 1):

Have the current theme in a session variable $theme;

then while loading the view, include the session variable in the path,

`$this->load->view('themes/'.$theme.'/<page>')`;

Comment: thanx @arun but is there it necessary to add the theme variable in the session

Comment: Sessions are arguably the best way to do this. You could also use a cookie, or even a URI segment, but this would need to be present in every URI to function correctly. See my post for another option

Comment: @binesh hey it seems you have the themes in http:://example.com/thems/. What do you mean by themes???... Is that the view files or just images&css. Coz view files cant be inside http:://example.com/thems/

Answer (score 0):

[Phil Sturgeon](http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2009/12/CodeIgniter-Template-library) and several others have written template libraries that support themes more or less out of the box. This allows you to keep MVC structure and is rather flexible.

More at [the docs](http://philsturgeon.co.uk/demos/codeigniter-template/user_guide/)

Answer (score 0):

I made a very simple theme switcher based on an existing library. Although the files are still in the views folder but inside the views folder are theme subfolders.

http://keithics.com/blog/php-programming/a-very-simple-theme-switcher-for-codeigniter